# Scores Being Deleted After Input in CodeIgniter Application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm encountering an issue in my CodeIgniter application where users' scores are mysteriously deleted after input.

The issue arises after successful input handling, where some users' scores are unexpectedly deleted from the database. I've thoroughly checked the code logic and can't seem to identify the root cause of this problem.

Key points to consider:

The deletion occurs only for certain users' scores, not all.
The deletion happens after successful input processing and database interaction.
I've verified that the data exists in the database before deletion.
No error messages or exceptions are thrown during the deletion process.
Any insights or suggestions on how to debug and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here's the breakdown of my application structure:

Controller

```
 public function entrymarks()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id', 'Subject', 'required|trim|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $data = array(
            'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => form_error('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
        );
        $array = array('status' => 0, 'error' => $data);
        echo json_encode($array);
    } else {
        $exam_group_student_id = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_id');
        $insert_array = array();
        $update_array = array();

        if (!empty($exam_group_student_id)) {
            foreach ($exam_group_student_id as $exam_group_student_key => $exam_group_student_value) {
                $attendance_post = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_attendance_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                $attendance = isset($attendance_post) ? $attendance_post : "present";

                $ca1 = is_numeric($this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value)) ? $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value) : NULL;
                $ca2 = is_numeric($this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca2_' . $exam_group_student_value)) ? $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca2_' . $exam_group_student_value) : NULL;
                $ca3 = is_numeric($this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca3_' . $exam_group_student_value)) ? $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca3_' . $exam_group_student_value) : NULL;
                $ca4 = is_numeric($this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca4_' . $exam_group_student_value)) ? $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca4_' . $exam_group_student_value) : NULL;
                $exam = is_numeric($this->input->post('exam_group_student_exam_' . $exam_group_student_value)) ? $this->input->post('exam_group_student_exam_' . $exam_group_student_value) : NULL;

                // Check if all input fields are NULL and delete the row if true
                if ($ca1 === NULL && $ca2 === NULL && $ca3 === NULL && $ca4 === NULL && $exam === NULL) {
                    // Delete the row from the database
                    $this->examgroupstudent_model->delete_row($exam_group_student_value);
                } else {
                    // Calculate total score
                    $tot_score = $ca1 + $ca2 + $ca3 + $ca4 + $exam;

                    // Insert into the database only if there is data to insert
                    $array = array(
                        'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => $this->input->post('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
                        'exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id' => $exam_group_student_value,
                        'attendence' => $attendance,
                        'get_ca1' => $ca1,
                        'get_ca2' => $ca2,
                        'get_ca3' => $ca3,
                        'get_ca4' => $ca4,
                        'get_exam' => $exam,
                        'get_tot_score' => $tot_score,
                    );
                    $insert_array[] = $array;
                }
            }
        }

        // Insert into the database only if there is data to insert
        if (!empty($insert_array)) {
            $this->examgroupstudent_model->add_result($insert_array);
        }

        $array = array('status' => '1', 'error' => '', 'message' => $this->lang->line('success_message'));
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
}
```

Model

```
 public function add_result($insert_array)
    {
        $this->db->trans_start(); # Starting Transaction
        $this->db->trans_strict(false); # See Note 01. If you wish can remove as well
        if (!empty($insert_array)) {
            foreach ($insert_array as $student_key => $student_value) {
                $student_value['exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'];
                $student_value['exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id'];
                $this->db->where('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id', $student_value['exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id']);
                $this->db->where('exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id', $student_value['exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id']);
                $q = $this->db->get('exam_group_exam_results');
                if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
                    $update_result = $q->row();
                    $this->db->where('id', $update_result->id);
                    $this->db->update('exam_group_exam_results', $student_value);
                } else {
                    $this->db->insert('exam_group_exam_results', $student_value);
                }
            }
        }

        $this->db->trans_complete(); # Completing transaction

        /* Optional */

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === false) {
            # Something went wrong.
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            return false;
        } else {
            # Everything is Perfect.
            # Committing data to the database.
            $this->db->trans_commit();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function delete_row($exam_group_student_id)
{
    $this->db->where('exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id', $exam_group_student_id);
    $this->db->delete('exam_group_exam_results');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to save exam scores for multiple students taking a single subject.

However, if there are no scores for a student for this subject, you delete all of this student's scores from the database - not just for the current subject, but for all subjects (s)he is taking.

That doesn't seem logical, so that might be where your problem is.

You can then fix this by also passing the subject to the delete function.

In your model:

```
    public function delete_row($exam_group_student_id, $exam_group_subject_id)
{
    $this->db->where('exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id', $exam_group_student_id);
    $this->db->where('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id', $exam_group_subject_id);
    $this->db->delete('exam_group_exam_results');
}
```

In your controller:

```
// Delete the row from the database
$this->examgroupstudent_model->delete_row(
    $exam_group_student_value,
    $this->input->post('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id')
);
```

Comment: oh my! the $exam_group_subject_id totally skipped me. Thank you for this